# UIImageJPEGRepresentation crashes in Share Extension on iPhone SE

Tags: ios, share-extension

I have a share extension that lets you crop an image and then upload it to our service. We call `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to get the image's data before we upload it, but causes a crash due to memory excessive memory. This only happens with large images, and (as far as we can tell) on the SE, and `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is not called first. This is happening when using the Photos app.

Is there anyway to safely call `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, or try to determine if the image is too large beforehand?

Comment: Have you considered simply getting the image URL instead of loading the whole image into memory?

Comment: The user can crop the photo before uploading it, so what we're converting to data is a `UIImage` created from a `CGContext`.

Comment: @rob Did you ever find a solution to this? Struggling with this as well.

Comment: would also love a solution - happens all the time with HEIC images on iPhone X / Xs

Answer (score 0):

Why not check for the image file size? If the image file size exceeds a certain quota, then resize it.

```
let image: Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
var imageSize: Double = (image.length)/1024 // in KB
```

Comment: `UIImagePNGRepresentation` also causes a crash

Comment: @rob can you post the thrown error? Along with that, can you create a sample Github repo containing your issue so as I be able to debug your code.

Comment: @eshirima its because of memory exception